# uploading image not working with running querys using foreach

Tags: php

i am strcuked in a unexpected problem..i am having many queries of creating and insert.

eg:

```
if (isset($_POST['install']))
{
$install_queries[] = "CREATE TABLE..............";


$install_queries[] = "CREATE TABLE..............";


$install_queries[] = "CREATE TABLE..............";

$allowedExtss = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png");
$extensions = end(explode(".", $_FILES["path2"]["name"]));
//echo $extension;
if (($extensions == "jpeg")|| ($extensions == "jpg")|| ($extensions == "png"))
{
  if ($_FILES["path2"]["error"] > 0)
   {
         $msgs = $_FILES["path2"]["error"] . "<br />";
   }
  else
   {
             move_uploaded_file($_FILES["path2"]["tmp_name"],
     "../images/" . $_FILES["path2"]["name"]);
   }

$filename2 = "images/" . $_FILES["path2"]["name"]; }

  $install_queries[] = "INSERT INTO TABLE(image) VALUES('$filename2')";

 foreach ($install_queries as $q)
 {
  //running queries here
 }
```

but on ruuning script it is inserting it with blank in image filed..but another fields are filled...............

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it uploading any images at all?

Perhaps only insert into the image table if the upload is successful.

```
if (isset($_POST['install']))
{
$install_queries[] = "CREATE TABLE..............";


$install_queries[] = "CREATE TABLE..............";


$install_queries[] = "CREATE TABLE..............";

$allowedExtss = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png");
$extensions = end(explode(".", $_FILES["path2"]["name"]));
//echo $extension;
if (($extensions == "jpeg")|| ($extensions == "jpg")|| ($extensions == "png"))
{
  if ($_FILES["path2"]["error"] > 0)
   {
         $msgs = $_FILES["path2"]["error"] . "<br />";
   }
  else
   {
         if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["path2"]["tmp_name"],
         "../images/" . $_FILES["path2"]["name"])) {

            $filename2 = "images/" . $_FILES["path2"]["name"];

            $install_queries[] = "INSERT INTO `image` VALUES('$filename2')";
         }
   }

 foreach ($install_queries as $q)
 {
  //running queries here
 }
```